# Saved Image disappears after restarting the application

Tags: java, android

I saved an image using sharedpreferences in navigation header picture. But when I restart the app, it resets to the default picture. Can anyone help me plz? 
I used intent to pass the image from MyProfile.java to MainActivity.class

**Main Activity:**

```
public void getIMG(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

            Bitmap _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
            imgProfile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.icon_round);
            imgProfile.setImageBitmap(_bitmap);

            imgProfile.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = imgProfile.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            _bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();

        }
```

**MyProfile(From where I received the image)**

```
[public void setProfilePhoto(View view){
        ImageView ivphoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userphoto);

        //code image to string
        ivphoto.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = ivphoto.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte\[\] image=stream.toByteArray();
        //System.out.println("byte array:"+image);
        //final String img_str = "data:image/png;base64,"+ Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
        //System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
        String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
        Intent _intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        _intent.putExtra("byteArray", image);
        startActivity(_intent);
        //decode string to image
        String base=img_str;
        byte\[\] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        ImageView ivsavedphoto = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.usersavedphoto);
        ivsavedphoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length) );

        //save in sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("userphoto",img_str);
        editor.commit();
    }][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the activity where you are showing the image use the following code to get the stored image from the shared preferences.

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
   String savedImage=preferences.getString("userphoto","");
Now, convert your image string to bytes etc.

Hope this will help you!!